# Disable ReactiveUI ItemsView.ItemTemplate hooking

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, reactiveui, itemtemplate

In `ItemsView` and subclasses of `ItemsView` such as `ListBox`, `ComboBox`, ..., ReactiveUI automatically sets the `ItemTemplate` property. This makes it easy to add a bunch of viewmodels to a list, bind the list to an `ItemsView` and have the correct views for each viewmodel.

However, sometimes this behavior is not desirable. For example, after binding a list of regular objects to a `ComboBox` I get the exception "Couldn't find view for `MyNamespace.MyObject`".

I could fix this by setting the `DisplayMemberPath` property on the ComboBox, however this property is not known at compile time. I want to bind `DisplayMemberPath` from the ViewModel to the View. Unfortunately, this produces the following exception: "InvalidOperationException: Cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a dummy value for `DisplayMemberPath` on the control and also keep the `DisplayMemberPath` binding with the ViewModel. ReactiveUI will see the dummy value and will not set the ItemTemplate property. The dummy value will be replaced by the binding as soon as a ViewModel is attached and everything will work as intended.